# Logo and Header Containers Not Resizing Properly

Tags: html, css, image

I have been working to get my company logo image and the background image to both resize according to the size of the screen they are viewed on. However, when I get the background image to resize properly the logo image will not change size at all. But, when I am able to get them both to resize, the logo image is then far too large and covers the width of the entire screen. Then when I change the width of the logo image to be smaller, then the background image shrinks to less than the width of the screen.

Here is the link to the landing page I am having issues with http://www.dorkdungeontestblog002.blogspot.com/

I would like the header image and logo image to produce the following effect while being responsive to different screen sizes, but as you can see by viewing the site, I am not achieving that result.

[Hopeful Header and Logo Appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTl7u.png)

If anyone can assist me with this I would really appreciate it, I've been at it for several hours now and it's just not working. Please let me know if there is any further information I can provide as well.

This is all of the code under the Header note...

```
/*---------[HEADER]---------*/
#header-holder { width:100%; height:auto; float:left; color:#fff; background-image:url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-dYSRZJJhqiM/VibgbmiBMeI/AAAAAAAADIU/OfLCyLyozy4/s1440-Ic42/DD%252520Landis%252520Large.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size: contain;}
#logo-container img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-size: contain;
}
.Page_title{font-family:'Droid Sans';font-weight:bold;font-size:27px;text-shadow:0px 2px 0px #000;width:800px;text-align:center;padding:10px;margin:17px auto 30px auto;}
.Page_content{font-family:'Droid Sans';font-size:13px;width:560px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0 0 56px 0;line-height:22px;color:#ffbda4;text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000}
```

Comment: With the logo separated in two elements, div header-holder and the image is impossible. Put the speaking dice inside the image and header-holder with background size: cover.

Comment: When I use background size: cover, the background image with the speaking die becomes so large that I can no longer see it. So I'm not sure I take your meaning, but I'm pretty sure that I am doing this wrong.

Comment: Sorry but at this moment your blog is closed so i can't see the code. But instead using an image in header-holder background you can use background linear gradient. Hera a good generator: http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator

Comment: Originally the background that was in place was a small repeatable tile and I replaced it with the image with the talking die. Then I adjusted the code to allow the background to fill the container so that the new background image would scale with the site, that's when I encountered the issue with the oversized Dork Dungeon logo. So, you're saying that I need to get rid of the talking die background image altogether and replace it with this gradient background? Also sorry, I didn't mean to lock the blog, I have reopened it.

Comment: Why the Dork logo and the talking dia is separated? And why in two different element? In this way they will never be aligned. I would do an element for the background (gradient) and an element for the logo.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing myself, but I am working with a template and have not been able to figure out how to remove the logo element without causing issues to the header. I have a background with the die and logo together, I just don't know how to get rid of the logo element so that it will still display the background properly.

Comment: Hi @GermanoPlebani I changed the background back to a repeating tile like it was in the original. Then used the image with both the logo and the talking die together. Then I added...

    img { 
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
    }

...to the Header to make the logo responsive, so now both the background and the logo for the header are responsive. Yay! Thanks for the suggestions.

Finally, I would like to make the counter responsive as well. Do you have any suggestions for how I could achieve that? Since the image and the timer are separate entities I'm once again a little lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote here for the editor.

```
.container,
#front_page_container {
    width: 100%
}
```

In this way the countdown remain centered. But in small resolution is too big, and i don't know if this class are used in another place of the site.
My advice is to change the layout. The template you are using is not responsive at all, so you have a lot of work to make it responsive.

Comment: Yea I can see how a lot of extra work is needed. I feel like I'm pretty happy with the way it looks now, being as how it's only temporary anyway. Thanks so much for all your help.